# jQuery UI save sortable position

Tags: jquery

I want to save the position of the `li` where I drag the element to in the `ul`. But it wont save the location of the li.

This is the html code:

```
<div class="col-md-12" id="formdrag">
     <ul>
         <li id="draggable" class="ui-state-highlight">Drag me down</li>
     </ul>

      <ul id="sortable">
           <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
           <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
           <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
           <li class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
           <li class="ui-state-default">Item 5</li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

Here is the script where i try to save the location:

```
<script>
$( function() {
var sPositions = localStorage.positions || "{}",
positions = JSON.parse(sPositions);
$.each(positions, function (id, pos) {
    $("#" + id).css(pos)
})
$( "#sortable" ).sortable({
  revert: true
});
$( "#draggable" ).draggable({
  connectToSortable: "#sortable",
  helper: "clone",
  containment: "#sortable",
  revert: "invalid",
  stop: function (event, ui) {
        positions[this.id] = ui.position
        localStorage.positions = JSON.stringify(positions)
    }
});
$( "ul, li" ).disableSelection();
} );
</script>
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Can you describe what you trying to achieve here? Your code doesn't have any problem to save and apply the position. You may want to add `position: absolute` to `#draggable` item in order to see the change. But It doesn't feel like that'd be your ultimate goal.

Comment: I guess `positions` is declared outside this code block. First thing to notice is that once you drop the item jQuery is cloning it, so dropped list item is a new tag in a different `ul`. In your `$.each(..) {..}` you probably might be able to do `$("#" + id).clone().attr("id", "").css(pos).appendTo( '#sortable');` for each position but I haven't tried it. I'm writing from a mobile phone.